# Finding Potential for specific Vector Field, help?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, scalar-fields

I've been trying to think of a potential to derive for the vector field

$$ \vec{F}(r,\theta,z) =-mg\sin(\theta) \hat{e}_{\theta} .$$

I'm assuming this is a force as in physics so the potential is assumed to respect $\vec{F}(r,\theta,z)= -\nabla\phi$. However, when I put the two equations on equal footing and begin to work on through the algebra/calculus it then appears as if I end up with my answer but certain integration constants come up with a result that would be a zero vector field with a constant potential field. Given that

$$ \nabla = \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\hat{e}_{r} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial \theta}\hat{e}_{\theta} + \frac{\partial }{\partial z}\hat{e}_{z}  .$$

Then

$$ - \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = 0 $$
$$ - \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} = -mg\sin(\theta) $$
$$ - \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial z} = 0 .$$

From the middle equation above it follows that

$$ \phi = -mgr\cos(\theta) + h(r,z) . $$

So my answer is nearly there and if I insert it into the third, to figure out the integration constant, I get

$$ h_{z}(r,z) = 0 $$
$$ h(r,z) = c_{z} + g(r) .$$

The final integration constant is then found by inputting $ \phi = -mgr\cos(\theta) + c_{z} + g(r) $ into the first relation. This leads to

$$ -mg\cos(\theta) + g_{r}(r) = 0 $$
$$ g_{r}(r) = mg\cos(\theta) $$
$$ g(r) = mgr\cos(\theta) + c_{r}.$$

Which results in $\phi = c_{z} + c_{r}.$ This doesn't seem right as I was expecting a function of $\theta$ and got a constant function. Did I do something wrong or is what I seek impossible? Is the field not truly conservative?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately your vector field tracks along circles around the origin, so if you perform a vector line integral around one circle, you will get a nonzero answer, in violation of the requirement that it be $0$ over any closed path in order for a potential function to exist.

Comment: The curl of this vector field (assuming I didn't make any mistakes) is $\frac{-mg\sin(\theta)}{r}\,\hat{\mathbf{e}}_z$, which is nonzero, so there is no potential function (recall that curl of a gradient is always zero).